# How to display cross sale products on checkout page Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cross-sells

Is it possible to add cross sell products on the checkout page? 
How can we do that? 
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show cross-sell products on checkout page by add below code to **checkout_index_index.xml**

> app/design/frontend/YourVendorName/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="crosssell.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="crosssell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: How to get cross sell products pro-grammatically in cart page?

Comment: this worked, just for Magento 2.4 i had to put the file under app/design/frontend/YourVendorName/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/layout

Comment: I've added the above code in my checkout_index_index.xml file but it's not working.. there is no block name as "content" so the above one is not a correct code to add the cross sell product in checkout page

Comment: (Magento 2.4.5) Need to add the `view_model` for this solution to work, so add this 2nd argument:
`<argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Listing\PreparePostData</argument>`

Otherwise Error: Call to a member function getPostData() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml:266